# Twitter Bootstrap DatePicker does not work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sarting from [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) I use the following html code:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

near the end of body I call this:

```
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>$('#dp3').datepicker(); </script>
  </body>
```

I also include the following

```
<link href="../css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when I click on the field no datepicker is open.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library as well? It's required for Bootstrap (and your current code) to work. Add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` right above the line where you include the datepicker library.

Comment: What does devtools say? Prob telling you the errors in the console when you click date picker.

Comment: @lan,  you are rights...I was referring to bad jquery library. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned previously, make sure you are including jQuery, and also wrap your datepicker initialization in the jQuery ready() function, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#dp3').datepicker();
});
```

See it working here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rUa7M/

Answer (score -1):

Or

```
$(function() {
  $('#dp3').datepicker();
});
```