# bootstrap datepicker doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use bootstrap datepicker and it doesn't work. I have looked at so many pages in bootstrap regarding the same problem. I tried almost all of them but in the end it didn't work. It acts as a normal text field.

I have included bootstrap-datepicker.js in my file as well.

I found this example and I don't know why its not working:

```
<div id="search_modal" class="modal hide fade" style="width:50%;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Search for a room</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" align="">
            <label>City/place</label>
            <div class="input-append"><input type="text" id="" name=""><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span></div>

            <label>number of people</label>
            <div class="input-append"><input type="text" id="number" name="number"></div>

            </br>

            <input type="text" id="dp1">            
                    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.2/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
            $( '#dp1' ).datepicker();
              </script>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" >
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class=""> 
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#search_modal" data-toggle="modal">Book a room ss</a>
        </div>
```

How can I solve this?

Here are some of pages I looked in order to solve the problem.

- [Bootstrap Datepicker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905170/bootstrap-datepicker-example)
- [Detect change to selected date with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009354/jquery-get-bootstrap-datepicker-value-on-input)
- [Twitter Bootstrap DatePicker does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155274/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-does-not-work)

Comment: Do you want exact? http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ymp5D/

Comment: yes, but I aready tried it it wont work for some reason. I have booth datapicker .css and .js in my file. I have JQuery as well but I am not sure y it wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="modal-body" align="">
        <label>City/place</label>
        <div class="input-append"><input type="text" id="" name=""><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span></div>

        <label>number of people</label>
        <div class="input-append"><input type="text" id="number" name="number"></div>

        </br>


        <div data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-02-2012" class="input-  append date myDatepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" size="16" class="span2">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" >
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class=""> 
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#search_modal" data-toggle="modal">Book a room ss</a>
    </div>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.0.2/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.myDatepicke' ).datepicker();
  </script>
```

it works for me.

p.s. add the whole thing just before you close your body tag

probably you also want to look into the [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goromlagche/ymp5D/58/) i edited your code
check it, it now works perfectly

Comment: add the whole javascript content just before you close the body tag.
What error are you facing?

Comment: Try the link I provided. Let me know if it does not work.
Check on your browser console whether the javascript file is loading or not.

Comment: I tried that website for 2 hours and I couldnt get it to work. I just dont know what goes wrong since it wont give me any errors.

Comment: did you checked your console? can you post the detailed code?

Comment: its a very long code. this is part of a form where u can select ur arriving time, and all implemented within the modal.

Comment: Can you put it on jsfiddle? it will be easy to test.

Comment: i just put my etire modal here.

Comment: I also added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goromlagche/ymp5D/58/), check it, works perfectly

Comment: it still doesnt work. Using Ctrl+Shift+J allowed me to see the error this error and its the only one.Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined . The datepicker is not working again

Comment: I have  added the jsfiddle link it has the exact code you provided and it works. Did you checked the jsfiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/goromlagche/ymp5D/58/

Comment: the dropdownmenu could be opening behind the modal try adding a z-index to .datepicker.dropdown-menu

.datepicker.dropdown-menu { z-index: 10000 }